# mvn clean install pulls in old snapshot version that don't exist

Tags: maven

I am trying to compile my code and with the latest version. I see that the old SNAPSHOT version is being picked up as well when I check the .war file. I ran the dependency:tree and checked if it had anything to do with it but nothing came up which said so.

Is there a way I can change the pom.xml to ensure this doesn't happen.?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml, and explain what command line you use to build, and which artefact is present as an outdated SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 0):

Run the build with `-U` and you get the newest SNAPSHOT versions.